# Raising TypeError when type is not correct

Tags: python, exception, typeerror

I'd like to call function `foo(a, b, c)`, where arguments can be `int` or `float`
Those arguments user inputs using `space` as a separator.
For example: `1 8 9`

In the same time user can input not only digits, bit make some typo like:
`1 8k 9`.
In this case I should raise TypeError and type the number of incorrect element

```
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())

for i, key in enumerate([a, b, c]):
   if not isinstance(key, (int, float)):
       raise TypeError(
           f'The type of {i + 1} element is incorrect')
foo(float(a), float(b), float(c))
```

In my code I have the next error: i can't write `k8` into `int` variable.

```
1 k8 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\digits\main.py", line 40, in <module>
    a, b, c = map(int, input().split())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'k8'
```

How can I raise the TypeError when user input `k8`?
And how to be in situation if user inputs `k8 9 5h`? I that case I need to Raise the TypeError with message `The type of 1, 3 element is incorrect`

Comment: Then you have to check if the input can be casted to float or int before this line: `a, b, c = map(int, input().split())`

Comment: If floats are allowed, why are you using `map(int, ...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
args = input().split()

f_args = []
errors = []
for i, arg in enumerate(args, 1):
    try:
        f_args.append(float(arg))
    except ValueError:
        errors.append(str(i))
if errors:
    raise TypeError(f"The type of {', '.join(errors)} element is incorrect")

foo(*f_args)
```

Comment: thank you! And if two of three inputs are incorrect like `5 9k 6j`, how can I type error message `The type of 2, 3 element is incorrect` ?

Comment: Then instead of immediately raising `TypeError` you'd need to accumulate the `i` values into a list so you can raise the error at the end.  lemme fix that.

Comment: Thank you, @Samwise It work fine for me! Need time to understand it but I will :)

Comment: Hi, @Samwise! Maybe you can hepl me: i need to call `foo` with any parameters, that user input. BUT if parameters include symbols like `8k` i need to raise `TypeError` inside my `foo` function, not before it

Comment: Just take the above logic and put it inside your `foo` function then.